# No HttpClient in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I recently downloaded and installed xamarin studio for my mac. I then began following a tutorial for c# coding with xamarin as I am a complete beginner. During the tutorial they use a HttpClient and add

using System.Net.Http

to their project so they can use the HttpClient. I was unable to do the same and only had the option of

using System.Net.NetworkInformation

This was a PCL project. I also tried a shared library project which gave more options including Cache, Mail, Sockets, Websockets, Security etc.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the [Microsoft.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/) NuGet package.

Answer (score 1):

This is what PCL is all about - by itself it contains only the most basic .NET functionality. You can write business logic and application flow in a PCL, but you can't reference most libraries that somehow interact with hardware, as this is platform-dependent.

There are two major solutions to this problem:

- **Dependency Injection**: the PCL defines an interface, and your platform-specific assemblies provide an implementation of this interface - this implementation can then reference all libraries available to the platform.
- **Bait-and-switch**: you create a PCL with all methods you require, that all throw *NotSupportedException* and include separate libraries *with the same signature* for each platform that have proper implementations of these methods. The compiler will only include the libraries of the specific platform. I personally consider this a bit of trick but this is how most NuGet packages provide their functionality directly available "as a PCL".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any extra packages to access `HttpClient` class. I've been using it for almost two years already in all of my projects. 
Example:

[image]

What I suggest:

Go to: `Edit References => Packages => Check System.Net.Http`. It should be there.

If you can't find it there, or list is empty under `Packages`(some kind of a bug) then reference it manually from here: `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.2/lib/mono/4.5-api`

Comment: Hum... I just realized it's been in Mono for a while. see https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7719/using-httpclient Don't remember where I found I should use Microsoft.Net.Http